# __repr__() returned non-string

Tags: python, string, traceback, repr

So I have a class method with which I would like to draw out the dictionary and it's values:

```
 def __repr__ (self): 
        for row in zip(*([ky]+map(str,val) for ky,val in (self.slovar.items()))):

           print"\t".join (row)
```

If it's like this, I get a desired output:

```
>>> test
n   n1  n2
1   a   2.3
2   b   2.1
3   d   2.5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#521>", line 1, in <module>
    test
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

but also a Traceback error.

If I return the value instead of printing it out, I only get this:

```
>>> test
n   n1  n2
```

It works fine if I make a custom method not the default 'system' one... (and I need it to be default)

Comment: You should not be `print`ing inside your `__repr__`.

Answer (score 13):

Your `__repr__` method is using `print` to output information, but has no `return` statement, so it is effectively returning `None`, which is not a string.

---

What you could do is:

```
def __repr__ (self): 
    parts = []
    for row in zip(*([ky]+map(str,val) for ky,val in (self.slovar.items()))):
       parts.append("\t".join (row))
    return '\n'.join(parts)
```

---

You might also want to have a look at [the `pprint` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).

Comment: yes, I know. if I return instead of print, I only get the dictionary key names, and no items...

Comment: @user1509923 I added an example of how you could actually return something

Answer (score 2):

your `__repr__(self)` method must return a string:

```
def __repr__ (self): 
 return "\n".join("\t".join (row) for row in zip(*([ky]+map(str,val) for ky,val in (self.slovar.items()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
def __repr__ (self): 
    rows = zip(*([ky]+map(str,val) for ky,val in (self.slovar.items())))
    return "\n".join("\t".join(row) for row in rows)
```

This way it remains readable and compact.